Trouble in initializing nested structure using a macro
I am trying to initialize nested structure pointers using a macro. I have a structure which looks like below. I am using the macro like below.
typedef struct {
        uint8_t Loc;
        uint8_t Module;
        uint8_t EventId;
} ErrorPayload;

typedef struct {
        uint32_t ErrorCount;
        uint32_t ReturnCode;
        ErrorPayload *Payload;
} ErrorInfo;

typedef struct {
        ErrorInfo *ErrInfo;
        uint32_t ArraySize;
        uint32_t Cols;
} ErrorMetaData;


#define ErrorMetadataInit(Mdata, _Buffer, _Size)                   \
        ErrorMetaData Mdata = {                                    \
                .ErrInfo = (ErrorInfo *) (_Buffer),                \
                .ErrInfo = {                                            \
                    .ErrorCount = 0,                                    \
                };                                                       \
                .ArraySize = (_Size - sizeof(ErrorInfo))/ sizeof(ErrorPayload), \
                .Cols = 0,                                         \
        }`

When I am trying to allocate buffer to ErrorInfo->ErrorPayload it give error. I tried this way.
#define ErrorMetadataInit(Mdata, _Buffer, _Size)                   \
        ErrorMetaData Mdata = {                                    \
                .ErrInfo = (ErrorInfo *) (_Buffer),                \
                .ErrInfo->ErrorPayload = (ErrorPayload *) (_Buffer + 16),                \
                .ArraySize = (_Size - sizeof(ErrorInfo))/ sizeof(ErrorPayload), \
                .Cols = 0,                                         \
        }

My main issue is I am not able to assign any value to structure member of ErrorPayload which is part of ErrorInfo structure. It always gives build error. Any help will be really helpful.
I wanted to allocate values to ErrorPayload structure inside defined macro.

_Buffer and _Size are reserved identifiers since they start with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter. Don't use those.

Please include an example of how you intend to use it too.

OT: It's conventional to use lowercase names for variables, including struct members... The difference between ErrorInfo and ErrInfo is likely keep you up until dawn, sometime in the future... I would not relish working with a codebase written like this. It's looking a bit like some COBOL listings I've seen ** shiver **. Suggest you get one small aspect working, first, and build up from there. (PS: "Any help" is a pretty b-r-o-a-d question to be asking. What is it you want?) Suggestion: write a function, and stay away from macros...

It would be helpful with an example of how you call the macro.

It is simpler to first fill _Buffer, assuming it has been defined as a pointer to ErrorInfo, this is how I'd write the code:
// Note that this sets all members to 0, not just ErrorCount
*_Buffer = (ErrorInfo) { .ErrorCount = 0 };
ErrorMetaData Mdata = {
    .ErrInfo = (ErrorInfo *) (_Buffer),
    .ArraySize = (_Size - sizeof(ErrorInfo)) / sizeof(ErrorPayload),
    .Cols = 0
}

Though I'd suggest making this a [[gnu::always_inline]] static inline function, and do away with macros.

_Buffer is being passed from other function. I wanted to allocate (_Buffer + 18) to ErrorInfo->ErrorPayload.

I have no idea what you mean. There's no context in your question. Kindly edit it and add all information in it.
